# The number of colours in greedy colouring is $\leq \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2E(G)+\frac{1}{4}} $

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

I am stuck with the following exercise:

> Let $\sigma$ be an ordering of the vertices of a given graph $G$ and let $\chi(G,\sigma)$ be the number of colours the greedy colouring algorithm uses. Show that
>
> $$\chi(G,\sigma) \leq  \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2E(G)+\frac{1}{4}}$$

I know that for the chromatic number of any graph holds $\chi(G) \leq \sqrt{2E(G)+\frac{1}{4}}$, but I do not see why this should hold for $\chi(G,\sigma)$ too. Could you help me?

Comment: Hint: Count edges at new vertex to the coloured subgraph when you need a new colour.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now.